# Proper use of tf.while_loop during inference?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is it possible to use `tf.TensorArray's` for reading and writing inside of the body of a `tf.while_loop`, but *not* pass them all through `loop_vars`?

I want to use `tf.while_loop` as part of a graph for WaveNet sound generation, which is a sequential generation mechanism that that generates the next amplitude value based on a window of previously generated ones.  But, I want to use this just during inference, so no need for gradients, and would call with `back_prop=False`.

Besides this, the loop `body` function must read and write intermediate values that must be remembered across time steps.

It looks like `tf.TensorArray` is the only option for reading and writing values in this way, but I notice that `tf.TensorArray.write()` returns a new `tf.TensorArray` that is meant to be returned by the body and used in the `loop_vars` argument.  Is this the best way to do this?

If I don't have a need for gradients, is there a simpler way to preserve state over the loop?

Comment: I dont get it. Are you trying to generate data on the fly or the graph itself? If you are generating data, stick to CPU it paradoxically performs better. You can use `tf.assign` to set intermediate values to some global variable.

Comment: I want to create a graph that implements WaveNet in generative mode -- at each iteration of the while loop, it computes another time step.  I hadn't considered `tf.assign`.  maybe that is the way to go!

Comment: Ahh...does `tf.assign` allow you to change the value of just one element (or a sub-range of elements) in a `tf.Variable`?  That's what I need.  Basically the same functionality as `tf.TensorArray.write(index, value)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tf.assign](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign) inside the `tf.while` to assign stuff inside a global variable.

EDIT: You cannot use `tf.assign` for assigning sliced indices of `tf.Tensor`, it is however allowed for `tf.Variable`. The argument sent to the while body is of type `tf.Tensor` and not `tf.Variable` so it wont work.

Here is some sample code.

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable([0,0])
assign_op = tf.assign(x[1],42)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(x)) # [0,0]
    sess.run(assign_op)
    print(sess.run(x)) # [0,42]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, using tf.assign with a slice of a variable as a target doesn't work inside a while_loop.  The error during graph construction is: `ValueError: Sliced assignment is only supported for variables`.  (It *does* work as you've shown, but not inside a while_loop for some reason)

Comment: see this new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51225805/tf-assign-to-variable-slice-doesnt-work-inside-tf-while-loop